# Entity Framework different foreign key data types

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys, type-conversion

I am in the process of using Entity Framework over a Visual FoxPro database (I haven't heard of it either). I've run into a problem creating the relationships using data annotations for the models.

I've simplified the classes:

```
public class Country
{
    [Key]
    public int Sid { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ObjectId")]
    public virtual ICollection<Heading> Headings { get; set; }

    ...
}

public class Heading
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string ObjectId { get; set; }
}
```

*Relationship: A Country has many Headings. (One to many)*

Note that `Country` has an Id which is an `int`. And the `ObjectId` (foreign key) on `Heading` is a `string`.

I'm receiving the following exception:

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> Country_Headings_Source_Country_Headings_Target: : The types of all
>   properties in the Dependent Role of a referential constraint must be
>   the same as the corresponding property types in the Principal Role.
>   The type of property 'Headingid' on entity 'Heading' does not match
>   the type of property 'Sid' on entity 'Country' in the referential
>   constraint 'Country_Headings'.

The issue is that the data types are different. Is there any way that I can have this relationship?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the primary key on Heading?

It reads as though you have a foreign key to a field that's not a key

Comment: @AntonyKoch The Heading's primary key is `Id`. The relationship is Country's `Sid` to Heading's `ObjectId`. I hope that made sense.

Answer (score 1):

*Edit*
This used to work with enums, may work with this?

```
public class Country
{
    [Key]
    public int Sid { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ObjectIdInt")]
    public virtual ICollection<Heading> Headings { get; set; }

    ...
}

public class Heading
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string ObjectId { get; set; }

    public int ObjectIdInt 
    {
        get { return int.Parse(ObjectId); }
        set { ObjectId = value.ToString() }
    }
}
```

Comment: Alas, this did not work. The same error occurred. Essentially, the relationship is Country's `Sid` to Heading's `ObjectId`. (As I mentioned in a comment above) The issue is that one of them is an `int`, and the other is a `string`. Also, I think your solution will cause some issues when saving/updating a Heading, as the `Id` column is the primary key for this table, not the `ObjectId`.

Comment: Right so the ObjectId is an int stored as a string?

Comment: For countries yes. However, the Heading table has foreign keys to other tables, where their primary keys are strings (Yep, it's one of _those_ tables).

Comment: I've just added an edit that may work, though again it's conjecture based on some hazy memories of enums

Comment: This is a very clever solution however it did not work (It's been nearly 2 hours of fiddling with this so I can't remember why it didn't work). Anyway, in the end I created a new model which uses the same table, but instead of a string, it uses an int as the `ObjectId`. +1 for effort :-)